# Wrapping an object and pretend it's an int

Tags: c++

I have a class `Object` that I'd like to use as if it were an `int`. In other words I want to pass this object to functions that accepts `int`, `int*` or `int&` so that the functions "see" actually ony the wrapped `int` value.

The code below illustrates what I want to do. I was able to write the code for `int` and `int*` but I'm not able to write the code for `int&`.

```
#include <cassert>   

class Object
{
public:
  int bla = 0;
  int val = 0;   // the int being wrapped

  Object(int v) : val(v) {};
  operator int() const { return val; };
  int *operator &() { return &val; };

#if 1
  int & operator() { return val; };   // << does not compile
#endif
};

int func(int val) {
  return val * 2;
}

void Bar(int* pval, int val) {
  *pval = val;
}

void Foo(int & pval, int val) {
  pval = val;
}

int main() {
  int val;
  Bar(&val, 123);
  assert(val == 123);
  Foo(val, 789);
  assert(val == 789);    

  Object o(8);
  assert(func(o) == 2 * 8);   // operator int()
  Bar(&o, 1234);              // int *operator &()
  assert(o.val == 1234);

#if 1
  Foo(o, 456);                // << does not compile
  assert(o.val == 456);
#endif
}
```

If  `#if 1` is replaced with `#if 0`, the code works as expected.

Could anybody point me into the right direction so `Foo(o, 456);` compiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the conversion operator, which you have the wrong syntax for.

It should be

```
operator int&() { return val; }
```